# React not rendering child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem rendering a child component in React 0.14.7—it's like React is just ignoring it completely.

Here's the method that initiates the render:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(
        view,
        {
            name: 'Rob'
        }
    ),
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Here's the main view being rendered:

```
var React      = require('react'),
    LogRegBack = require('log-reg-back-view');

var RegisterView = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        console.log(1);
        return React.DOM.div({
            children: [
                'Hello, ' + this.props.name,
                LogRegBack,
                ' How are you?'
            ]
        })
    }

});

module.exports = RegisterView;
```

And here's the LogRegBack child component that is being ignored:

```
var React  = require('react'),
    styles = require('../../../css/log-reg-back.css');

var LogRegBack = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        console.log(2);
        return React.DOM.img({
            className: styles.logRegBack,
            src: '/assets/log-reg-back.jpg'
        });
    }

});

module.exports = LogRegBack;
```

I'm using webpack to bundle everything, so I thought maybe I had a configuration problem, but I can see my LogRegBack code in the output files, and webpack does rebuild as expected when I make changes in my LogRegBack file (I'm using the `--watch` option). Moreover, when I launch my web page I see '1' being logged in the console, but I don't see '2'. For some reason, React isn't even calling the `render()` method of the LogRegBack component.

If I add the image directly as a child in my main view file, the image shows up just fine:

```
children: [
    'Hello, ' + this.props.name,
    React.DOM.img({
        className: styles.logRegBack,
        src: '/assets/log-reg-back.jpg'
    }),
    ' How are you?'
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm used to using JSX, but I suspect you need to use createElement when you're passing `LogRegBack` as a child to `RegisterView`.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct; however, I decided to follow [this recommendation](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html#react-without-jsx) in the docs and create a factory: `LogRegBack = React.createFactory(require('log-reg-back-view'));`

Comment: That's probably the better way to do it, glad you found that.